# Parameters in Query mongoexport

Tags: bash, mongodb, mongoexport

I need help to specify parameter values in the query during mongoexport.

Here is the example

```
-q '{Id:{$eq:"$ID"}}',
```

I specified `ID=$1` in the Bash shell script but when scheduler runs it, it is not exporting anything. Here ID is a column in a collection.

Script is as follow

```
#!/bin/bash
ID=$1 
mongoexport -u test -p test --authenticationDatabase admin -d test -c test -q '{Id:{$eq:"$ID"}}' -o test.json
```

Comment: Running `mongoexport` in what? Bash or Powershell? You should show the script you are trying to run this in.

Comment: Running in Bash, Here is the script  ID=$1 mongoexport -u test -p test --authenticationDatabase admin -d test -c test -q '{Id:{$eq:"$ID"}}' -o test.json

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50448111/edit) link on your question you need to use for details.

Answer (score -1):

assign whole query to be passed to mongoexport in a variable.
and use that variable like this:

```
query_var="generate_query_here_you_can_do_all_kind_of_concatenation_if_needed"    
mongoexport -u test -p test --authenticationDatabase admin -d test -c test -q "$query_var" -o test.json
```

Don't forget to put query_var in double quote in mongoexport query.

This is not a great solution but yeah it worked for me.